# Encrypting strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, encryption

Currently im using

```
$key="pass";
$val="secret";
$encp=mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $val, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

But when i call `printf($encp)`
No value is displayed,im using PHP version 5.2.17

Is there a better way to do it.Please help.

EDIT:

```
<?PHP

    define('SECURE_KEY','Somekey');

    function encrypt($value){
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SECURE_KEY, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    }

    function decrypt($value){
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SECURE_KEY, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
    }
    $temp=encrypt("teststring");
    printf($temp);
    ?>
```

Comment: What is `$hash`? Do you mean `$encp`?

Comment: Add a complete code please ... missing `$hash` , `$key` and '$val` ...

Comment: @diewie Yes.Sorry its updated.

Comment: see these different approaches in encryptoin...http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update (27/09/17):

Since [mcrypt_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) is DEPRECATED as of **PHP 7.1.0**. Ive added a simple encrypt/decrypt using [openssl](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php).

```
function encrypt($string, $key = 'PrivateKey', $secret = 'SecretKey', $method = 'AES-256-CBC') {
    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', $key);
    // create iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret), 0, 16);
    // encrypt
    $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $method, $key, 0, $iv);
    // encode
    return base64_encode($output);
}

function decrypt($string, $key = 'PrivateKey', $secret = 'SecretKey', $method = 'AES-256-CBC') {
    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', $key);
    // create iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret), 0, 16);
    // decode
    $string = base64_decode($string);
    // decrypt
    return openssl_decrypt($string, $method, $key, 0, $iv);
}

$str = 'Encrypt this text';
echo "Plain: " .$str. "\n";

// encrypt
$encrypted_str = encrypt($str);
echo "Encrypted: " .$encrypted_str. "\n";

// decrypt
$decrypted_str = decrypt($encrypted_str);
echo "Decrypted: " .$decrypted_str. "\n";
```

Try these: **(PHP < 7.1.0)** If your using > PHP 7.1.0 see above.

```
define('SECURE_KEY','Somekey');//Assigned within a config, pref outside of root dir

function encrypt($value){
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SECURE_KEY, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
}

function decrypt($value){
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SECURE_KEY, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
}
//Simple usage
$encryptedString = encrypt('This String Will Be encrypted');
echo decrypt($encryptedString);
```

Edited from source - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

Comment: How to assign values to SECURE_KEY and Somekey

Comment: `define('SECURE_KEY','SomeOtherKeyOrSecretCodeNotGreaterThen32Chars');
`

Comment: How to give values to SECURE_KEY and SomeKey

Comment: @techno not sure what you mean, once a constant is defined then its usable to full scope

Comment: I mean if want to assign 'password; to SECURE_KEY.How to do it?

Comment: SECURE_KEY should be assigned within a config of such, one sec ill add usage

Comment: ,This is not working the page is not printing any values,i have posted the complete code see EDIT.

Comment: You should use `print_r()` instead and the output prints `›µÞ/<g»2CÆYÈÆ·ƒjãrß/½rC›â#U*`

Comment: I replaced it with print_r($temp); But the page is still not showing anything

Comment: @techno Add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top and see if there are errors. It works...

Comment: @techno glad you got it sorted

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Is there any way to achieve the same results with openssl?

Answer (score 0):

Try these PHP functions [convert_uuencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uuencode.php) and [convert_uudecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uudecode.php):

```
function encrypt_decrypt ($data, $encrypt) {
    if ($encrypt == true) {
        $output = base64_encode (convert_uuencode ($data));
    } else {
        $output = convert_uudecode (base64_decode ($data));
    }
    return $output;
}

$enc_txt = encrypt_decrypt ("PASSWORD TEXT", true);
echo $enc_txt."\n";
// LTQkJTM0VT0vNEQwQDUkNTg1YGBgCmAK
echo encrypt_decrypt ($enc_txt, false);
// PASSWORD TEXT
```

This is much simpler and does not depend on libraries installed in PHP

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this unless we know what the situation is. This alters the text, but it's essentially as secure as plaintext

Comment: for passwords you should use mcrypt and your choice of cipher although Bcrypt is popular for a reason. PHP 5.5+ has built in functionality for this with unique salts for each password, if you want backwards compatibility in php 5.4 you can use this library https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat